# Leg tightens/hurts when stretching in bed

Tags: pain, stretching

You ever wake up from a deep sleep, give your body a good stretch and think to yourself "man that felt good!"? Well unfortunately for me, I've had the exact opposite happen a couple times in less than a week. This has also happened in the past but didn't think much of it, that maybe it was just a cramp.

The other night I awoke, stretched out my legs and my lower RIGHT leg tensed up so bad to the point it felt like the muscle just locked up. I tried to move my leg and foot around to alleviate the pain, which helped a little, but was hard to do so.

When I did get up a couple hours later for work, my lower leg was still very sore and hurt to put a lot of pressure down on it. Very similar experience this morning but it didn't happen as bad, I was able to feel the pain before it got too bad and stop myself from stretching. (You ever try to stop yourself mid-stretch in the morning? It's not fun...)

Anyways, I do have RLS so I don't know if that is adding to the situation. Although last night wasn't as bad as some nights. As well as an issue with my lower back with the muscle above my left hip. So I'm a little concerned on why this would happen. Do I maybe have a damaged muscle in my leg? It's never happened to my left leg, only my right.